# How set rotation angle a page in itext 7

Tags: itext, itext7

How can i rotate page at a specified angle(for example 25 degrees)?

```
PdfCanvas content = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());
 for (int i =1 ; i <= srcDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
 PdfFormXObject page = srcDoc.getPage(i).copyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
content.add(page...);

}
```

Can i set RotationAngle to work with  PdfFormXObject ? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is by using an `AffineTransform` (from `com.itextpdf.kernel.geom`):

```java
PdfCanvas content = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());
PageSize pageSize = pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize();
PdfFormXObject page = srcDoc.getPage(1).copyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(25 * Math.PI / 180, (pageSize.getLeft() + pageSize.getRight())/2, (pageSize.getBottom() + pageSize.getTop())/2);
content.concatMatrix(transform);
content.addXObject(page, 0, 0);
```

*([RotatePageXObject](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/RotatePageXObject.java#L42) test `testAddPage25Degree`)*

`AffineTransform.getRotateInstance` is documented to

```
 * Get an affine transformation representing a counter-clockwise rotation over the passed angle,
 * using the passed point as the center of rotation
```

so we feed it the angle (transformed to radians) and the coordinates of the page center.

Applied to this source PDF it creates this result:

[image: source][image: result]

Comment: can i  define pagesize for tilt?(pagesize + pagesizeTilt)? So that the content fit current area.

Comment: You use `pdfDoc.addNewPage()` which creates a new page with the default page size of the document. There is an overload of `addNewPage` that accepts a `PageSize` parameter. Use that overload and specify a page size that is appropriately enlarged in **all** directions, not only right and top.